# active_scaffold Error in Flash messages (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.1, activescaffold

Rails 4.1.6
Ruby 2.2.2
active_scaffold 3.4.28

I have error when enter in a view of active_scaffold

no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

```
<% for name in [:info, :warning, :error] %>
  <% if flash[name] %> <<< ------- Got The Error
    <div class="<%= "#{name}-message message" %>">
      <%= display_message flash[name] %>
      <% if request.xhr? %>


 /home.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/active_scaffold-3.4.28/app/views/active_scaffold_overrides/_list_messages.html.erb,      
 /home.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/active_scaffold-3.4.28/app/views/active_scaffold_overrides/_list.html.erb,
```

I dont know why I have problem with the flash messages, some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You have used two times double quotes which would not work. 
As you have passed symbol in the class you need to convert in to string `name.to_s`

There are many ways to print

```
<div class="<%= name.to_s %>-message message">
```

or

```
<div class='<%= "#{name.to_s}-message message"%>'>
```

Comment: your edited answer is right. I think this should work . Symbol needed to be converted in string to get right result @Arv

Comment: I got the error is in <% if flash[name] %>, and this code is into the active_scaffold gem. I have error is in flash variable

Comment: @DanielArenas but what I have mention that is working ?? because <div class="<%= "#{name}-message message" %>"> is also wrong

Comment: I have mention name should be like this name.to_s have you seen that